# Jumbotron with dotted overlay and post title

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first website made from scracth, and now I'm facing some challenges to give it the look I want.

Based on Bootstrap, I'll the post title inside the Jumbotron, with the Featured Image as background. To make it more visible, I want to put an overlayed dotted div, instead of editing each image darker to match my post title.

I was succeed with almost everything, but I can't put the title ABOVE the dots, so it's covered too.

```
<div id="capa" class="jumbotron text-center" style="background-image:url('PHP TAG FOR FEATURED IMAGE');">
<h1 class="titulo-post"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<p class="data-post"><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_time('l, j \d\e F \d\e Y')); ?></p>
<div id="dot-matrix"></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
#capa {
   background-size: 100% auto;
   border-radius: 6px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
}
#capa h1 {
   z-index: 9999;
}
#dot-matrix {
    background: url(http://www.the215guys.com/wp-content/themes/the215guys/images/graphics/pattern-1.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean, "over"? 3d over? or just at the top of the div? dot-matrix is absolutely positioned at top:0, so there's no way to display anything "over" it in the 2d direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the ´z-index´ order try this:

Working sample here: http://codepen.io/Tmeister/pen/qOEmVy

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
#capa {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}
#capa h1 {
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
}
#dot-matrix {
    background: url(http://www.the215guys.com/wp-content/themes/the215guys/images/graphics/pattern-1.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Gracias Enrique!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `z-index` you must explicitly set the position of your element to either `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

```
<div id="capa" class="jumbotron text-center" style="background-image:url('PHP TAG FOR FEATURED IMAGE');">
    <div id="dot-matrix"></div>
    <h1 class="titulo-post"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p class="data-post"><?php echo ucfirst(get_the_time('l, j \d\e F \d\e Y')); ?></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding: 100px 0;
    height: 300px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
#capa {
   background-size: 100% auto;
   border-radius: 6px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
}
#capa h1 {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.data-post {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 200px;
    color: white;
}
#dot-matrix {
    background: url(http://www.the215guys.com/wp-content/themes/the215guys/images/graphics/pattern-1.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the working example:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v2g17uqe/)